# how to use toogle switch in windows phone application

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I am trying to add the toogle switch in windows phone application, I had searched in Internet also but didn't find the solution for using toogle switch. I followed the example as shown below. but it's showing some error , and saying toogle switch did't exist. Can anybody suggest what is happening here and a better way to use toogle switch. The Code which I used is from C# corner, and is like this.

```
  xmlns:tool="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" // 

  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">


            <tool:ToggleSwitch x:Name="tglSwitch" 
                               Header="wifi" 
                               Checked="tglSwitch_Checked" 
                               Unchecked="tglSwitch_Unchecked"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: The error is noticed in this " <tool:ToggleSwitch x:Name="tglSwitch" " part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ToggleSwitch` is a control that can be found in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) library.

You can easily add that library to your project via NuGet: right click on your project -> "Manage NuGet packages" then search for "WPtoolkit".